# How to change the Auto layout reference object?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I want to change the reference object by code in xib , here is the situation :

[image]
at first , I set the yellow view 's top to blue view 's bottom has a static margin by auto layout constraint , and now I want change the yellow view 's reference object from blue view to red view. I know if the reference object not change , I can change the constraint by drag it to my view and user constraint = 10 to change the constraint , but I don't know how to change the reference object , can some one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First delete the old constraint. Then right-click and drag from the Yellow View to the Red View and this should pop-up, then select the constraint you want to add.

Now the constraint you just added is between the Red View and the Yellow view.

[image]